# Update Table from Another Table where column IN multiple values

Tags: mysql, wordpress

My first attempt at this failed and I had to do a pesky restore on a really large table.

I've tried multiple queries, I think I am getting close, but everything I find provides a syntax error (I'm assuming because of the `IN` clause)

The tables are identical, but `wp_postmeta_price` only contains the value I want to restore `_regular_price`

Here's what the `wp_postmeta` table looks like

[image]

Lots of different columns here of various sorts.

The values in this table I'm trying restore I created another table `wp_postmeta_prices` with ONLY the `meta_value` of `_regular_price` I'm wanting to restore based from the `meta_key` and `meta_id`

Here's what that looks like

[image]

This may not be the easiest way, but what I did was export this table to an excel spreadsheet and used a tool to create the `post_id` column to a csv format so that I could use the `IN` clause for multiple unique instances

Here's maybe the closest I've gotten

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta_price ON wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_postmeta_price.post_id
AND wp_postmeta.meta_id = wp_postmeta_price.meta_id
SET wp_postmeta.meta_value = wp_postmeta_price.meta_value WHERE '_regular_price' IN (2498,2443,2424,2518)
```

but this is not correct.

Can anyone please help me with the proper syntax, or enlighten me on a better possible solution for this?

Comment: WHERE wp_postmeta_price.post_id IN (2498,2443,2424,2518)

Comment: Do you mean `UPDATE wp_postmeta
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta_price ON wp_postmeta.post_id IN (2498,2443,2424,2518) = wp_postmeta_price.post_id
AND wp_postmeta.meta_id = wp_postmeta_price.meta_id
SET wp_postmeta.meta_value = wp_postmeta_price.meta_value;`? The query works but no rows are affected...

Comment: UPDATE wp_postmeta
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta_price ON wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_postmeta_price.post_id
AND wp_postmeta.meta_id = wp_postmeta_price.meta_id
SET wp_postmeta.meta_value = wp_postmeta_price.meta_value WHERE wp_postmeta_price.post_id IN (2498,2443,2424,2518)